# If the linear mapping $M: W \rightarrow V$ and $L: V \rightarrow W$ are both surjective (onto), then $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Here the vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional**

I think this statement is true.

I tried to prove it using **Rank-Nullity Theorem** because I want to show that the dimension of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is the same such that I can prove $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

My steps are following:

Assume $dim(Range(L))$ = n and $dim(Range(M))$=m. Then by **Rank-Nullity Theorem**, I can establish two equations:

n = $dim(Range(L))$+$dim(Ker(L))$

m = $dim(Range(M))$+$dim(Ker(M))$

Since L and M are surjective, $dim(Range(L))$ = $dim(W)$= $m$.

Similarly, $dim(Range(M))$=$dim(V)$= $n$

By subtracting the top equation to the bottom one, I get:

$n - m$ = $m-n+dim(Ker(L))-dim(Ker(M))$

Then I got stuck here. How to show the $dim(Ker(L))$ = $dim(Ker(M))$ in this case? I know that the $Ker(M)$ is a subspace of $Range(L)$ and $Ker(L)$ is a subspace of $Range(M)$. However, I do not know if this fact will help me in proving this question. If not, how should I proceed?

I appreciate anybody who can offer an idea on this question.

Comment: The claim is true whether or not $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional.  It follows from the fact that the isomorphism class of a vector space (over a given base field) consists of all vector spaces of the same dimension.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this! I am currently taking my second Linear Algebra course and my instructor hasn't introduce the idea of field or isomorphism class. However, it is good to know it since I will learn them in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n = dim(W)$ and $m= dim(V)$

Then $n = dim(Im(M)) + dim(Ker(M)) = m + dim(Ker(M)) ≥ m$

And $m = dim(Im(L)) + dim(Ker(L)) = n + dim(Ker(L)) ≥ n$

Then $n = m$ so $W$ is isomorphic to $V$

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is very concise and clear! Much appreciated!